# Converting int into enum type

Tags: java

Hello I seem to be having trouble with a project that I am working on. I have created an enum type named Shift for breakfast lunch dinner swing), 
I then have a switch with 4 cases to choose which one it is.

However when I try to create an object without any user input, and set the value to a random number from 1-4, there is a message that appears saying "incompatible types : int can not be converted to Shift"

any help would be appreciated!

EDIT*
I currently have this

```
private void getShiftAsInput()

{

  Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print(" Please enter " + getName()
           + "'s Shift by Number:\n"
                   + "1.  Breakfast\n"
                   + "2.  Lunch\n"
                   + "3.  Dinner\n"
                   + "4.  Swing ========> ");
  String inShift = cin.nextLine();
  switch(inShift){
      case "1": shift = Shift.breakfast; break;
      case "2": shift = Shift.lunch; break;
      case "3": shift = Shift.dinner; break;
      case "4": shift = Shift.swing; break;
      default: getShiftAsInput(); break;
  }
}

public enum Shift { breakfast, lunch, dinner, swing }
```

and in the main classs am trying to do this:

```
   RestaurantWorker[] arr;
   arr = new RestaurantWorker[6];

   arr[0] = new Manager();
   arr[1] = new Manager("John Edelman", "8521100900", 3, 10, 1000, 40000);
   arr[2] = new WaitStaff();
   arr[3] = new WaitStaff("Kelsey Green", "5662902901", 3, 36, 10.25, 40, 10, 2 );
   arr[4] = new KitchenStaff();
   arr[5] = new KitchenStaff("Jeff Brown", "8596042909", 2, 30, 10, 30, 0);
```

but am getting an error for the argument after the phone number.

Comment: Why should an `Enum` be the same as or comparable to an `int`?

Comment: If you use `Shift.values()`, you can access an array of all the values. These concepts are covered in [Enum Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html). My advice would be to do some reading and grasp the concept fully, rather than just copying a solution.

Comment: Hey Kacper, it’s actually very unclear what you are trying to achieve. Could you please add some code and tell us what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how your code should be, the type mismatch is because you have to pass ENUM into the switch case.

```
public class Practise {
static enum SHIFT {
    BREAKFAST, LUNCH, DINNER
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SHIFT key = SHIFT.BREAKFAST; // hardcoded for example, but can be dynamic
    switch (key) {
    case BREAKFAST:

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

}

When you generate random integer values, you can change your logic to assign an ENUM value to the variable. Something like,

```
SHIFT key = SHIFT.values()[getRandomIndex()];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide a way to convert `int` to your target `Enum`.

This is my way to do that:

```
public enum Shift {
   BREAKFAST(1), LUNCH(2), DINNER(3), SWING(4);

   private final int value;

   public Shift(int value) {
      this.value = value; 
   }

   private static final Map<Integer, Shift> SHIFT_MAP = new HashMap<>();
   static {
      Arrays.stream(Shift.values()).forEach(s -> SHIFT_MAP.put(s.getValue(), s));
   }

   public static Shift of(Integer value) {
       return SHIFT_MAP.getOrDefault(value, BREAKFAST); // Here you provide a default Shift value if input wrong value
   }
}
```

And in your switch statement:

```
Shift shift = Shift.of(value);
switch(shift) {
  case BREAKFAST:
 ... bla bla
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting an an int type to an Object Type, instead of "Shift = int" try "Shift.YourDataField = int"

"YourDataField" is whatever field you set in your object, and it should be an int type