# JPA retrieve enum with white space

Tags: java, jpa, enums

I have a spring boot application and I have defined some POJO classess to specify the data model. In a table I want to store enum columns but I have an enum data type and some of the enums contains spaces.

```
enum DataEnum {
   Workload("Workload"),
   ReleaseContent("Release content"),
   "VerificationProc"("Verification proc")

   private String name = "";
    DataEnum (final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public DataEnum fromString(String value) {
        return DataEnum.valueOf(value);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

I have a POJO entity class as below:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(FieldId.class)
public class Field {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Id
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private DataEnum sheet;

    ...
}
```

When I try to retrieve data from the database I get:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown name value [Release
>   content] for enum class [data.util.DataEnum]

Comment: What is "enum containg space". Show code

Comment: So, you're trying to get the enum by the name value as opposed to the string value of the enum (i.e.; ReleaseContent)?

Comment: don't use toString() to show the name. Make a getName() method or something.

Comment: @VeselinDavidov Why is that? The Javadoc of `java.lang.Enum` states "An enum type should override this method when a more "programmer-friendly" string form exists.". You can't rely on `toString()` on an enum to return the constant name - for that, there is a final method `Enum.name()`

Comment: Hmm can it be the ORM calling getName() instead of name() ?

Comment: Which values do you have in the database? The enum constants or the "name" field

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JPA cannot map your string to enum because it cannot find any enum with that name exists.

Internally, the @Enumerated use the method `Enum.valueOf` to convert the DB String to enum constant. The DB String required to be exactly the same to the enum constant identifier.

That is, if you want to store `DataEnum.ReleaseContent`, you have to store it as `ReleaseContent` not `Release content`.

In your case, if you want to store value different than your enum identifier, you can declare a custom converter:

```
@Converter
public class DataEnumConverter implements AttributeConverter<DataEnum, String> {
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(DataEnum enum) {
       // Convert your enum to DB value
    }

    @Override
    public DataEnum convertToEntityAttribute(String dbValue) {

       // Convert String to your enum
    }
}
```

You can see [My Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50192383/converting-int-into-enum-type/50192435#50192435) for an example how to convert String to enum

And in your entity:

```
@Column
@Convert(converter = DataEnumConverter.class)
private DataEnum sheet;
```

Comment: Or just store the enum constants in the database instead of their names ;) You are not even sure that names are unique and the constants are.

Comment: Do you see the current data structure of OP: `ReleaseContent("Release content"),`? The friendly name is not match with enum identifier. And many times, you want to save a name different than just enum identifier. It's job of programmer to provide such unique name for enum

Comment: I see the data structure and still if he uses @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) the value that goes to the database will be ReleaseContent -> the enum constant. The problem comes because somehow in the database he has the other value "Release Content"

Comment: I tried the converter method, but I get : Could not write JSON document: Could not read entity state from ResultSet : .. nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Could not read entity state from ResultSet

Comment: Why it is related to JSON anyway? What are you doing? Try to return entity to browser? Post me the full stacktrace dude

Comment: No, was not related to this issue. The solution provided by you worked fine. Thanks!